# What does the text under "Militia Commander" title mean?

Tags: dwarf-fortress-premium

I just noticed that there is text under the "Militia commander" title that I believe wasn't there before. Does this mean anything in particular?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the name of the squad they're in. When you first create a squad, the militia commander will automatically be added to that squad.

My nobles screen:

[image: Nobles display, militia commander]

And the squad view:

[image: Squad display]